# WebSQL threw an error

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, pouchdb, web-sql

I'm using pouchdb with websql and cordova , for the large data it is thworing me thw following error , please help someone

```
WebSQL threw an error Error: Failed to allocate a 124256264 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 96MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 125165360, growth limit 201326592
```

Comment: You're out of memory.

Comment: @Flimzy any solution for this ?

Comment: how to do it , sorry i don't have much knowledge on it @Flimzy

Comment: To get more memory, you buy a device with more memory, or you perform a memory hardware upgrade. To use less memory, you close some apps that are using memory, or refactor your app to use less memory.

Comment: Free storage is completely irrelevant to the question of memory.

Comment: 4gb ram , no other applications are running , isn't it a good configuration @Flimzy

Comment: That's entirely subjective. It depends on what your application requires. And your application obviously requires more than the available RAM. You may also have per-process memory limitations in place. But the obvious answer to your question, if you just read the error message, is that the memory allocation failed.